# Getting issue with navigation in React JS with Microfrontend Application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack-5, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

I have 2 application which is running on different servers.

Scenario:

1. Parent App - (Routes: /home, /aboutus, /contactus)
2. Child App  - (Routes: /admin/dashboard, /admin/customers etc.)

I have connected this child app into parent app using Module Federation Plugin (Webpack 5). In my parent application there is route called /admin.

When [URL]/admin is called that time I am loading remote Child app.

How can I access /admin/dashboard path inside my Parent application and If I am on /admin/dashboard page and refresh the application which will try to find /admin/dashboard which is not there in parent application. How can I resolve this issue?